# Submit form after AJAX checks

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my code :

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var form = this;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (($('#datepicker').val() == '') || ($('#heureDebut').val() == '') || ($('#heureFin').val() == '') || ($('#rechercheVilleChargement').val() == '') || ($('#rechercheVilleChargementDPT').val() == '') || ($('#rechercheVilleLivraison').val() == '') || ($('#rechercheVilleLivraisonDPT').val() == '') || ($('#numeroCommande').val() == '') || ($('#numeroOT').val() == '') || ($('#affrete').val() == '') || ($('#client').val() == '') || ($('#depot').val() == '')) {
    swal({
      title: "Erreur",
      text: "Des champs obligatoires sont vides, complétez ces champs puis validez. ",
      type: "error",
      confirmButtonText: "Retour au formulaire",
      confirmButtonColor: "#333570"
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "MODEL/ajaxCheckAddTransport.php",
      cache: false,
      data: $("#form").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == "NO") {
          return true;
        } else {
          swal({
            title: "Erreur",
            text: "L'OT " + ($('#numeroOT').val()) + " existe déjà. Impossible de créer le transport.",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonText: "Retour au formulaire",
            confirmButtonColor: "#333570"
          });
          return false;
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('La requête AJAX n\'a pas abouti, contactez l\'administrateur');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="MODEL/addTransport.php" id="form">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="titleprghp text-center">
          <span class="prg">Chargement</span> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="titleprghp text-center">
          <span class="prg">Livraison</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All is OK, I get the right value from AJAX query, "NO" and "YES" when I have to get it. The problem is that, I can't submit my form when I get the "NO" value...

```
if (data == "NO")
{
   return true;
}
```

Here is my problem...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you have used `preventDefault()` to stop the form submission. Also, using `return` in the AJAX callback is moot as will not affect the outer `submit` handler at all.

To solve the issue, call the `submit()` method of the underlying `form` directly. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data == "NO") {
    form.submit(); // use the 'form' variable you created within the submit hander here...
  } else {
    swal({
      title: "Erreur",
      text: "L'OT " + $('#numeroOT').val() + " existe déjà. Impossible de créer le transport.",
      type: "error",
      confirmButtonText: "Retour au formulaire",
      confirmButtonColor: "#333570"
    });
  }
},
```

[**Simplified example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2bmttgb6/)

I would also strongly suggest you change your `MODEL/ajaxCheckAddTransport.php` endpoint to *NOT* return a plaintext response. Return JSON instead, with a boolean property that contains the validity state.

Comment: This is exactly what i did just before. When I put 'form.submit()', and when i click on the button, nothing happens. I tried to debug it with IE and the line form.submit() is underlined in red with "Membre introuvable" which means "impossible to find member".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (data == "NO")
    {
       $("#form").submit();
    }
```

Comment: I tried. And I have a strange reaction... Nothing was happening. And I tried to add : alert(data) just after success : function(data). Then when i click on the button, the message with cata "NO" is repeated endlessely... Like if the form was submitted again and again..